# $x+iy\mapsto\sin (x+iy)$ on the strip $-\pi \lt x\le -\frac{\pi}{2}$, $-\infty \lt y\lt \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

My textbook says exactly this (if $z=x+iy$):

> From the identity $\sin (−z + \pi) = \sin z$ it follows that the image of the strip $-\pi\lt x \le -\frac{\pi}{2}$, $-\infty \lt y\lt\infty$, is the same as the image of the strip $\frac{\pi}{2}\lt x \le \pi$, $-\infty \lt y\lt \infty$, under $w = \sin z$.

This doesn't seem correct to me. I think that, instead, it should be

> ...the image of the strip $-\pi\lt x \le -\frac{\pi}{2}$, $-\infty \lt y\lt\infty$, is the same as the image of the strip $\pi \lt x \le \frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\infty \lt y\lt \infty$, under $w = \sin z$.

It seems that one would get the result in the textbook if $\sin (-z)=\sin z$ was used, which is of course not correct for all the values in the strips.

Is there an error in the textbook, or is my result wrong?

Comment: Why is not correct?

Comment: @Bernard Because the strips differ by $2\pi$ only on the boundaries.

Comment: Or maybe it should be the strips $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $x\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$

Comment: I think you are right.  The textbook seems to be mistaken, and your suggestion works.

Comment: @Bernard But if we compare $-\pi\lt x\le -\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi\lt x\le\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then they differ by $2\pi$ everywhere.

Comment: @mjw "Or maybe it should be..." could you please write what do you mean by *it* exactly? Thank you.

Comment: Start with $x\in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$, then $-x\in[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}]$, and $(\pi-x)\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.  Since $y\in(-\infty,\infty)$, we need not mention it.  All strips involve all values of $y$.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't so careful about the endpoints for $x$.  Please, if you like your strips half-open and half-closed, include strict inequality at one endpoint of each.

Comment: Now you are just adding $2\pi$ to the $x$ coordinate.  That's also okay, but has not much to do with $z\mapsto \pi-z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  The textbook is mistaken.

If $z=x+iy$ and you start with $$ -\pi<x\le-\frac{\pi}{2}, \quad  -\infty<y<\infty
$$

then $\pi-z$ is in this strip: $$ \frac{3\pi}{2} \le x<2\pi, \quad  -\infty<y<\infty.
$$

although, .... it looks like the question has been edited!